# how to pass datatable column to stored procedure as parameter

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, datatable, dynamic-sql

```
create procedure insert_data
(@Table-name,
@column-name,
@column-value)
as 
Begin 
......
end
```

I have a data-table that has 3 columns named as `table-name`, `column-name`, `column-values` and I want to pass this to a stored procedure.

In the stored procedure, I want to fetch the data-table values and I want to
   create a dynamic SQL that should create a INSERT statement
   using the `table-name`, `column-name`, `column-values` from `data-table`.

Example:

```
insert into @table-name(@column-name) values(@column-values)
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you go this path I strongly recommend to read [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html).

You don't specify RDBMS you use so I use `SQL Server` as example:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), col1 VARCHAR(100),
                     col2 INT, col3 DATETIME);
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[insert_data]
    @Table_Name    SYSNAME
   ,@Column_Name   SYSNAME
   ,@Column_Value  NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   -- here you should check metadata if table/column exists
   -- you can get also the column datatype and validate with `TRY_PARSE`

   SELECT @Table_Name = QUOTENAME(@Table_Name),
          @Column_Name = QUOTENAME(@Column_Name);

   DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)  =
     N'INSERT INTO @Table_Name(@Column_Name)
       VALUES (@Column_Value);';

   SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '@Table_Name', @Table_Name);
   SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '@Column_Name', @Column_Name);

   -- debug
   -- SELECT @sql

   EXEC dbo.sp_executesql
          @sql
          ,N'@Column_Value NVARCHAR(MAX)'
          ,@Column_Value;
END
GO
```

Calling:

You can use `CURSOR/LOOP` to read data from your table and call procedure for each row.

```
EXEC [dbo].[insert_data] 
   @Table_Name     = 'mytable' 
   ,@Column_Name   = 'col1'
   ,@Column_Value  = 'Text Sample';
GO

EXEC [dbo].[insert_data] 
   @Table_Name     = 'mytable' 
   ,@Column_Name   = 'col2'
   ,@Column_Value  = '100';
GO

EXEC [dbo].[insert_data] 
   @Table_Name     = 'mytable' 
   ,@Column_Name   = 'col3'
   ,@Column_Value  = '2015-11-27T00:00:00';
GO
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/31847/1/0)**</kbd>

Remarks:

1. Do not treat this as production ready code just as stub/starting point!!
2. Your `INSERT` does not make sense for me because it should also `UPDATE` existing rows (inserting one value a time will leave rest of fields with `NULL/default value`)
3. Be aware of possible `SQL Injection` so quote identifiers, parametrize value
4. Check if table/column exists and provided value can be casted to its datatype, if not add code that will cast `@Column_Value` not every datatype can be implicitly caster from `string`
5. Reconsider using normal `INSERT INTO`